# How make a emmeans plot with interaction and many factors

Tags: plot, interaction, multi-factor-authentication, emmeans

I would like to make a emmeans plot taking all behaviour variable into account, which are columns, related to two other columns. The behaviour variables were create based on scale, from 1 to 10.

colA (numeric) | col B --------- to -------- J (factor) | col H (2 ordinal/factors)

I have made some clmm models on each behaviour variable in interaction with colA, and I don't know if I have to take all models to make emmeans plot or if I can just take the basic data of my dataset ?
Then, I would like to have in x-axis the scale of behaviour variable and in y-axis all the behaviour variables group by colH. I tried this but obviously it doesn't work..

```
Beh <- as.matrix(mydata[,c(6:33)]) #select all behaviour variables
Pers.emmeans <- emmeans(mydata,colA~Beh, by= colH) 
plot(Pers.emmeans, comparison = TRUE) +theme_bw()
```

I also tried to check on internet how I can manage this but nothing about code
Please any ideas ?

Comment: `emmeans()` doesn't analyze a dataset, it summarizes a *model*.

Comment: Ok I have this model :
cm <- clmm(colH~colA*beh_col+(1|ID),mydata), but instead of beh_col I would like every column about behaviour variable so I made this :
cmtot <- clmm(colH~colA*(col B + ......+colJ) +(1|ID),mydata)
But this model doesn't work 
Does someone have an idea ? I don't know if it's clear...